# Segue between scenes without initializing scene

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am fairly new to Swift and am having immense trouble with a multi-scene spritekit situation.

Let me give some background:

My game is attempting to have three screens; an intro, an upgrade scene, and a play scene. My intro scene simply either initializes the upgrade scene or initialized the play scene as per the users touch (there are two buttons on the intro screen, choose to either play or go to the upgrade scene). From the upgrade screen you can press a variety of buttons that change variables effecting the sprites speed, texture, and a variety of other stuff. When you are finished there is a button that the user can press to initialize the play scene. When the sprite touches another node in the play scene, the intro screen then initializes again.

The tricky part that I have been working on is trying to get the upgrade screen to have an effect on the play screen without declaring all of the variables global (this worked for the first play, but upon trying to press anything on the screen again I got a massive amount of EXC and SIGABRT errors, probably for bad memory access).

For example:

UPGRADESCENE:

```
class UpgradeScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var groundspeed = 5.0
    var hero = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Hero")

    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent){

        for touch: AnyObject in touches{

            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.sbutton1 {
                groundspeed = 25.0
            }

            if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.sbutton2 {
                hero.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed:"Hero2")
            }

            if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.playscenebutton {
                var scene = PlayScene(size:self.size)
                let skView = self.view! as SKView
                scene.scaleMode = .ResizeFill
                scene.size = skView.bounds.size
                skView.presentScene(scene)
            }
        }
}
```

So the hope would be that when I press that third button, the changes brought about from the first two buttons will function in the functions that carry it in the next scene:

PLAYSCENE:

```
class PlayScene: UpgradeScene{

    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

        runningbar.position.x -= CGFloat(groundspeed)

        //SO THE GROUNDSPEED CHANGE FROM THE OTHER SCENE WOULD WORK HERE...
        //BUT IT JUST INITIALIZES THE ORIGINAL DECLARED VALUES
    }
}
```

The PlayScene is inheriting from the UpgradeScene and will run the groundspeed with the original values, but doesn't recognize the change made for the button press.

**QUESTION**

How can I get my upgrade scene to effect my play scene without causing a bunch of memory errors? Can I just open it differently instead of initializing it and losing the changes made in the upgrade scene to the original variable values, textures etc...?

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to not make `PlayScene` inherit from `UpgradeScene`, especially if your only intention is to use the updated values. In fact, as you discovered yourself, the changes don't show in `PlayScene`.

You're misinterpreting the idea of inheritance. Your comment `//BUT IT JUST INITIALIZES THE ORIGINAL DECLARED VALUES` is just as I would expect. You can't inherit changes. Inheritance doesn't work like that.

You're correct in avoiding global variables.

What you might want to do is set up a class that holds and manages the changes. I'd advise you to use `NSUserDefaults` to track changes, and use a class to interpret the changes.

For example, a racing game might let you customize the engine for different speeds. I would store the speed as an integer and for any option they pick in the customization screen, I would update the value in `NSUserDefaults`. When the time comes for the player to play the game, I'll have a class that interprets the number stored in `NSUserDefaults` and gives the car the appropriate speed.

Comment: Thank you Kelvin. So the idea would be to declare the variable within NSUserDefaults and then call the integer from the NSUserDefaults class in my playscene functions? I'm slightly confused on how this would look and why it wouldn't in the same way without NSUserDefaults.

Comment: Sure. In your upgrade scene, whenever a user makes modifications, you could save a value into `NSUserDefaults`. 

Then, when you move over to the PlayScene, you can make a call to `NSUserDefaults` to query the value, and adjust your modifications appropriately. 

You don't have to use `NSUserDefaults`; I just think it's the easiest method for games of simple complexity. It'll also persist your data, (if you need it).

Comment: If you don't need to record any data for next sessions, I've done apps where you simply make use of the `prepareForSegue` method for the UIViewController to pass along values to the `GameViewController`, where it sets the changes in the `GameScene`. 

Note that this set up would be different from yours; You'll be using a segue to access the `GameScene` every time, and the your other views won't be `SKScene`, but `UIViewController`.